# How to find a value in a multidimensional dictionary by another value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I created a multidimensional dictionary which looks like this:

```
Dict = {{'ID': '395', 'Status': 'ACT', 'Type': 'PER', 'Full_Name': 'Sarah ABITBOL'}
        {'ID': '542', 'Status': 'ACT', 'Type': 'PER', 'Full_Name': 'Tugba KARADEMIR'}
        {'ID': '392', 'Status': 'ACT', 'Type': 'PER', 'Full_Name': 'Alisa DREI'}
        {'ID': '100', 'Status': 'ACT', 'Type': 'PER', 'Full_Name': 'Viktoria VOLCHKOVA'}}
```

Is there an easy way to the name `"Sarah ABITBOL"` if I have the ID `395`?

Or should I better create the dictionary this way:

```
Dict = {'395': {'Status': 'ACT', 'Type': 'PER', 'Full_Name': 'Sarah ABITBOL'}
        '542': {'Status': 'ACT', 'Type': 'PER', 'Full_Name': 'Tugba KARADEMIR'}
        '392': {'Status': 'ACT', 'Type': 'PER', 'Full_Name': 'Alisa DREI'}
        '100': {'Status': 'ACT', 'Type': 'PER', 'Full_Name': 'Viktoria VOLCHKOVA'}}
```

I would prefer the first one since it is easier to create this way.

Comment: That's not a "multidimensional dictionary", it's a syntax error.

Comment: if there are many calls, it is better to create a  diffrent dictionary.

Comment: The first one is closest to a `set` if there were commas, however, it couldn't be that either, because `dict`s are not hashable.

Answer (score 1):

The latter method is the way to go, but you need to format it correctly:

```
Dict = {
    395: {'Status': 'ACT', 'Type': 'PER', 'Full_Name': 'Sarah ABITBOL'},
    542: {'Status': 'ACT', 'Type': 'PER', 'Full_Name': 'Tugba KARADEMIR'},
    392: {'Status': 'ACT', 'Type': 'PER', 'Full_Name': 'Alisa DREI'},
    100: {'Status': 'ACT', 'Type': 'PER', 'Full_Name': 'Viktoria VOLCHKOVA'}
}

Dict[395]['Full_Name']
```

The result is `'Sarah ABITBOL'`.

Don't forget the commas that separate the dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is the most logical way to organise that data:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
    status: str
    type: str
    full_name: str

data = {
    395: Person('ACT', 'PER', 'Sarah ABITBOL'),
    542: Person('ACT', 'PER', 'Tugba KARADEMIR'),
    392: Person('ACT', 'PER', 'Alisa DREI'),
    100: Person('ACT', 'PER', 'Viktoria VOLCHKOVA')}
```

Then you get from `395` to `'Sarah ABITBOL'` this way:

```
data[395].full_name
```